# Proverb to express this concept: foregoing immediate gratification in favor of long-term reward

Tags: proverbs

In other words, if you forego getting X in the short-term, you'll get more X than you'd have otherwise in the longer-term.

I'm drawing a blank at the moment.  The proverb, "a penny saved is a penny earned", doesn't quite capture this idea but it's close.

Comment: [*The Ant and the Grasshopper*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ant_and_the_Grasshopper)

Comment: that's a fable, not an idiom or proverb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **good things come to those who wait**

> [All things come to he who waits](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/27000.html)
>
> **Meaning**
>   A literal meaning, advocating patience.
>
> **Origin**
>   Used, but probably not originated, by Violet Fane (1843-1905) in her poem *Tout vient ß qui sait attendre*.
>
> 'Ah, all things come to those who wait,'
>   (I say these words to make me glad),
>   But something answers soft and sad,
>   'They come, but often come too late.'
>
> <sup>Source: Phrase Finder</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's surprising there's no proverb for this.

The only one I can think of that's similar: **"It's not what you earn, it's what you keep."**  As with "A penny saved is a penny earned", it is as you say similar but exactly the thought at hand.

Note that Albert Einstein is said to have said either "The most powerful force in the universe is compound interest," or, "Compound interest is the eighth wonder of the world. He who understands it, earns it ... he who doesn't ... pays it." This quote is often used to express the thought at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Though not a perfect fit but the saying [slow and steady wins the race](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slow+and+steady+wins+the+race) may suggest that you'll get a better result with patience and time:

> - Prov. If you work slowly but constantly, you will succeed better than if you work fast for a short while and do not continue. (Associated with Aesop's fable of "The Tortoise and the Hare.")

The Free Dictionary